# Python 3 - POST request with urllib.request returning HTML data

Tags: python, api, post, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to access a website's API with a POST request but it's returning HTML and I don't know why.

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://matchbook.com'
loginReq = '"method": "/bpapi/rest/security/session", "params":{"username": "xxxxx","password": "xxxxx"}'

req = urllib.request.Request(url, loginReq.encode('utf-8'))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
print (response)
```

This returns a stream of HTML which basically says I'm using an unsupported version of Internet Explorer and I should consider upgrading to a newer one.

I've spent some time looking online and it's hard to find any detailed information about get/post/put/delete requests in Python 3, most of the helpful information I've found involves using the "requests" module in Python 2.  Would switching to Python 2 make this easier?

Here's the information they give in the documentation:

Resource URL:
URL: matchbook.com URN: /bpapi/rest/security/session

Example request:
POST /security/session
{
"username": "j_henry",
"password": "******"
}

Example response:
{
"session-token": "1418_1234567890",
"user-id": 1418,
"account": { // Same as GET /account API response.
...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you're incorrectly sending data to the API; aka your loginReq variable.

You need to use curl or some equivalent tool to figure out exactly what parameters and values need to be posted.  Something along the lines of

```
curl --data "method:/bpapi/rest/security/session&params={username=j_henry&password=**}" https://www.matchbook.com
```

Once you have the request down you can start worrying about actually programming it.

Comment: I somehow didn't see your response until now but thank you for taking the time to respond, and you were correct in that I wasn't passing the parameters correctly.  I ended up switching to the requests module as that was more straightforward than urllib.  requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(loginReq), headers=mbHeader).json(), with data and header being dictionaries, got the job done.